# Concatenate value of the same key between to objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to concatenate certain key value which is present in both object? Like on my example below, I want to concatenate the functions init_callback of both objects.

```
var defaultOptions= { init_callback: t.ActionEvent, name: "foo"}; 
var options = { init_callback: function(e) {}, name: "bar" };

var config = $.extend(defaultOptions, options);
```

Output:
`config.init_callback: t.ActionEvent, function(e) {}, name: "bar"`

Comment: your output format is invalid

Comment: You can't concatenate functions. You could put them in an array.

Comment: There's nothing built-in that will do this. How would it know that `init_callback` should be concatenated, but `name` should be replaced? You'll need to write your own merging function that handles each property appropriately.

Comment: Instead of an array, you could generate a function that calls both of the functions in the inputs.